# Should i Install redux package for using redux-toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Need redux-toolkit package for redux package, or it will work without it

Comment: No need , since redux is present in redux toolkit package, but yeah download react-redux package

Comment: No, redux tool kit and react-redux is enough

Answer (score 1):

You should install redux-toolkit only. As you can see here [redux toolkit npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@reduxjs/toolkit), redux-toolkit has redux as its dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Look at theirs [package.json](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/master/packages/toolkit/package.json), you should install libs from peerDependencies. Redux is in dependency so if you do not import and use it somewhere you don't need to install it (it would be installed automatically).